# MATLAB GUI stop button issues

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

EDIT: I rephrased my question a bit, because I have a better understanding of the problem now and there was a lot of unnecessary info in the first draft.

I am creating a standalone MATLAB application, which needs a toggle button that can initiate and stop a looping script.

Based on this [helpful video](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/03/how-to-loop-until-a-button-is-pushed-in-matlab/), I was able to implement this idea like this in my gui.m file:

```
function startBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    if get(handles.startBtn,'Value')
        set(handles.startBtn,'String','Stop Recording');
    else
        set(handles.startBtn,'String','Start Recording');
    end

    while get(handles.startBtn,'Value');
        disp('looping..');
        pause(.5);
    end
```

This script works as expected, but when I replace the contents of the while loop the function I would like to loop, the button stops working. It still toggles when I push it, but the callback only gets called the first time the button is pushed. Here is what my final code looks like:

```
function startBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    if get(handles.startBtn,'Value')
        set(handles.startBtn,'String','Stop Recording');
        pause(.1);
    else
        set(handles.startBtn,'String','Start Recording');
        disp('Recording Stopped')
    end

    while get(handles.startBtn,'Value');
        myFunction();
    end
```

When I push the start button, this callback runs and the loop starts. The `pause(.1)` is needed to get the text to change - if I don't include a pause, the loop initiates, but the text on the button does not change.

After this, no subsequent button pushes do anything. The button toggles on the GUI, but `startBtn_Callback` never gets called and the loop runs indefinitely. This is a problem because my end user will not have access to the MATLAB console.

To give a bit more information about my function: its a method that records audio for 5 seconds, does some processing, then outputs some graphs. I want this loop to repeat indefinitely until the user pushes stop.

I think that the issue is that MATLAB seems to only be able to run one function at a time, so when `myFunction()` is running, the callback can't be initiated. The reason it worked in the first example is because there was a pause between loop calls. I can't have this pause, because a requirement of the project is to record every possible second.

How can I make a reliable stop button for this process?

I am running MATLAB R2012b 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawnow() is the function I was looking for. Putting that after myFunction() forces Matlab to handle any stacked up GUI calls before proceeding with the loop.

This code creates a reliable start/stop toggle button for an indefinite and continuous process:

```
function startBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

  if get(handles.startBtn,'Value')
      set(handles.startBtn,'String','Stop');
      drawnow();
  else
      set(handles.startBtn,'String','Start');
  end
  while get(handles.startBtn,'Value');
      myFunction();
      drawnow()
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet

```
a=get(handles.startBtn,'Value')
while a
    myFunction();
end
```

the value of `a` is assigned once, and never changes afterward. Thus, the `while`-loop will either never run, or it will loop forever.

```
while get(handles.startBtn,'Value')
    myFunction();
end
```

will query the value of the button at every iteration, however, especially if `myFunction` doesn't take very long to execute, there will be lots and lots of java requests that may make your GUI sluggish.

This is why the example you followed uses the `pause` line, so that the loop only executes every .5 seconds or so.

If you don't want to have the query in the `while`-line, you can alternatively write

```
%# read inital value of a
a=get(handles.startBtn,'Value');
while a
    myFunction();
    %# update a
    a=get(handles.startBtn,'Value');
end
```

Comment: Ok I understand the problem with a. When I put the query back in the while line and update a in the loop, a evaluates to 0.. Why is the loop even running? The get query returns 1 in the while line, and 0 in the a= line.

Comment: Nvm, the loop was initiated before the value changed. The loop did not run again in this case.. Still didn't solve the main problem though, and now, for some unknown reason, I can't recreate a situation where the stop script runs.